# How to put image in a file and at the same time in that file I also want to put String data also?

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtable

I have created a RegistrationFrame 
to register here where a user puts personal information about themselves:

[image: Registration Frame]

That information, of all the users are stored in a file (FileInput/OutputStream,ObjectInput/OutputStream are used). After that when an user LoggedIn (user authentication)
all those personal information about that user will display in a JTable like this:

[image: PersonalInfo_Table]

Now I want to add one more thing is that, user's own photo so that when an user will register themself, they also can able to add their own photo. So what method I should use in my RegistrationFrame (RegistrationFrame image given above).. And after logged In of an user's account, that photo also should show in that same JTable (PersonalInfo_Table)?

Comment: I don't think can store image in non image files.

Comment: I have asked two questions there .and i don't think my first question is wrong. so if you dont know the answer thats ok but plese dont press the down vote  @marshalcraft

Comment: I did not down vote.

Comment: One of the simpler ways to store both a string and image is to put them both in the same zip archive. Java has good support for zip compression. The archive can have whatever extension suits your app. Another way to store them is to encode the image as text, and put the string and (text) string into an XML file. Tip: Don't presume that someone who comments on a question has voted (either up or down).

Comment: thnqu,, and Happy new year :)

Comment: Ok I'm not sure about storing an image in a non image file, however you CAN store text into a .png for example in the `anxillary chunks`. Which is then easily decodable if you have standard file stream open the .png as a text file. The .png ignores anxillary chunks it does not know how to decode and as such should leave your text alone whilst being safe. Also I think it is a good question prior to editing and not sure why it is down voted. Now it just seems you want to know how to display jpeg in the java window which I'm sure there are already existing questions which have been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the `.png` file specification for details.

Here I have inserted right before the `IEND` critical chunk an `anxillary chunk`. This chunk is non critical and if the decoder does not know how to decode it, it will safely ignore it. The chunk fields that we care about and in order are...

`4 bytes length` (not including the 4 bytes for the length)

`4 bytes type` (If you make the third byte a lowercase ASCII character it forces the codec to ignore it (ensuring safety))

`n bytes` (Text for your message).

Here is a cat .png with embedded text `Hello I am a kitty.`
[image]

`00 00 00 0E 74 45 58 74 48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 49 20 61 6D 20 6B 69 74 74 79 2E`

`....tEXtHello I am kitty.`

which is easily parsed from the .png as a text file by searching for the chunk type I created `tEXt` (Not confused with existing chunk type named `tEXT`) in text or `74 45 58 74` in hex. `tExT` where 3rd letter is lowercase ensures the decoder ignores it. The length of the text is 4 bytes before where `tEXt` was found and is the length of the string + 4 bytes. It's up to you how you want to encode data into a string.

**Summary**

So a `.png` is an excellent medium to store an image and some text in one portable file safely. There maybe other file formats and ways to do this too. It's up to you if you think the coding/decoding of text into it is worth your time compared to two separate files.